# How to Generate a JavaDoc for a Android Library Project that includes the Already available documentation of the jar that the library project is using

Tags: android, javadoc, doc

I am developing a android library which would be distributed as ".jar" . My library project includes a already available jar in it. so now i would like to make a documentaion for my library which can link to the already available jar docs of the jar that my project is including.

eg. My library's class is A which implements interface B(a inteface of jar that my project is using), now in my documentation when some one click on B, then i should also include the documentation of that library too.

I have a quick release. rply asap guys .

Comment: _I am developing a android library which would be distributed as ".jar"_, Android SDK currently doesn't provide this kind of function.

Comment: android sdk provide functionality to make android library project ! thankyou for commenting :)

Comment: now if you know how to generate java doc for library with in  the jar only

Comment: Read [Changes to Library Projects in Android SDK Tools, r14](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2011/10/changes-to-library-projects-in-android.html), distribute Android Library Project as jar will support in the future.

Comment: thanks yorkw, i'll have a look